# Do I have to install any snaps in a "server environment"?

Tags: server, system-installation, snap, vmware

I have installed VMware 16 Pro: (https://www.vmware.com/uk/products/workstation-pro/workstation-pro-evaluation.html) on a trial basis and with that I installed Ubuntu Server 22.04 from the official [Ubuntu website](https://ubuntu.com/download/server).

During installation, there is a menu where I can select to install "Featured Server Snaps" (popular snaps in a server environment).

[image]

Do I have to install any snaps from this menu on my server installation, and are my selection here important for server operation?

Comment: It's not asking you to install a "snap server environment". It's saying "these are popular snaps ***in*** server environments". Whether you want to install them is up to you. You can choose to proceed without selecting any, if you want. Recommendations are offtopic as they're primarily opinion polls.

Comment: This is no longer opinion based, as it doesn't ask for recommendations (after I edited the question).

Answer (score 3):

In short, you don't need to install any of these snaps on your server. In fact as a beginner, I would advise you NOT to install them during the installation (with Livepatch as a possible exception - see later).

There are several reasons for this:

- None of these snaps are vital for server operation - they are all optional applications for different purposes, and can always be installed later if you need them
- Most of these applications (except Livepatch and possibly other Canonical exclusive apps) can be installed through several means, where snap is only one of several options (some can also be installed with `.deb` packages, some with Docker etc.)
- In my opinion, this menu is mostly "marketing fluff" from the Ubuntu creators, with the purpose of promoting snap packages

I believe you should do some more research about what you want to do with your server, and if you intend to use any of the snap packages for this. If this is the case, each package can also be installed from the [Snap Store](https://snapcraft.io/).

There is one possible exception though: [Canonical Livepatch](https://ubuntu.com/security/livepatch/docs). This application is only available as a snap package, and it can livepatch various official Ubuntu kernels for Intel x64. If you need livepatch on your server, it's safe to install this. Even if you don't use it, it doesn't take up much space, and neither does it use any resources if it's not used.

I believe the only scenario where this menu makes sense is, if you've already decided that you need to run X, Y and Z of the applications present on the list, and that you want to use them as snap packages. Then this menu gives an easy shortcut to install those applications. But that's about it, as I see it.

Comment: Agreed. I run a couple of snap-free 20.04 servers, one cloud and one physical.